# Как использовать ячейки, рядом стоящие с активной ячейкой

Tags: google-apps-script

Как использовать ячейки, рядом стоящие с активной ячейкой?
Использую скрипт для отправки емейл из гугл таблицы.
Сейчас скрипт находит в выделенном диапазоне отправителя, тему письма и тело письма.
Требуется переписать скрипт так, чтобы я вставал на ячейку с телом письма и скрипт подцеплял автоматом слева от активной ячейки емейл получателя и тему письма.

[гугл таблица со скриптом](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Veqcb50luBA8rUU1PtLZ3u2gDTiQPusOcNLD5tu59x8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится мапить строку во что-то осязаемое. Т.к. у нас известны заголовки, то можно построить массив объектов с определенными ключами

```
function sendSelectedEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var headers = sheet.getRange('1:1').getValues()[0];
  var data = sheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(), 1, sheet.getLastColumn(),
      activeRange.getLastRow()).getValues()
    .map(function(row, i) {
      var item = headers.reduce(function(p, h, j) {
        if (h)
          p[h] = row[j];
        return p
      }, {});
      item._row = activeRange.getRow() + i;
      return item;
    });

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    Logger.log(item);

    var row = item._row;
    var emailAddress = item.email;
    var subject = item.subject;
    var message = item.message;
    // Mail App.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    //   cc: 'test@ya.ru',
    //   replyTo: 'test@ya.ru'
    // });
  })
}
```

Результат лога

```
[20-01-26 00:06:00:140 MSK] {
 "email": "test@ya.ru",
 "subject": "Привет",
 "message": "Пойдем гулять?",
 "_row": 2
}
[20-01-26 00:06:00:140 MSK] {
 "email": "test@bk.ru",
 "subject": "Работа",
 "message": "Собеседование",
 "_row": 3
}
[20-01-26 00:06:00:141 MSK] {
 "email": "test@gmail.com",
 "subject": "Прощай",
 "message": "Конец",
 "_row": 4
}
[20-01-26 00:06:00:141 MSK] {
 "email": "",
 "subject": "",
 "message": "",
 "_row": 5
}
```

Можно безболезнено менять колонки местами.